# Lock file for access on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Using `portalocker` we can lock a file for access through the following way:

```
f=open("M99","r+")
portalocker.lock(f,portalocker.LOCK_EX)
```

The `lock` over the file can be removed using

```
f.close()  #or
portalocker.unlock(file)   #needs `file` ie reference to file it locked ..pretty obvious too
```

Can this same thing be done by any other way in python wherein

1. We can lock the file for access
2. Restart Python (so no longer have the original Python file object or file number).
3. Unlock the file for access in the new process.

I cannot save `f` or `file object` so can't use `pickle` or something either. Is there a way using the Python standard library or some `win32api` call?
Any windows utility will also do...any command line from windows?

Comment: So the basic question underlying is that *Can I lock a particular file in Python while doing any operations on it*?

Comment: @BhargavRao not with it....its like `lock a file`,forget about it,`later unlock only knowing the filename and path`

Comment: Locking is done *per file descriptor*; the value returned by `fileobj.fileno()`. If you cannot store at least that value you cannot later unlock.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so based on only path of file we cant do it right?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here? Locking files between program runs? So lock the file, exit Python, start another script, unlock?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes sort of!!!!!!!!! :( ..... is der a way ?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use subprocess to open the file in notepad or excel:

```
import subprocess, time

subprocess.call('start excel.exe "\lockThisFile.txt\"', shell = True)

time.sleep(10) # if you need the file locked before executing the next commands, you may need to sleep it for a few seconds
```

or

```
subprocess.call('notepad > lockThisFile.txt', shell = True)
```

As written you need shell = True, otherwise windows will give you a syntax error.

(subprocess.Popen() works as well)

You can then close the process later using:

```
subprocess.call('taskkill /f /im notepad.exe') # or excel.exe
```

Other options include

-write some C++ code and call it from python (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx)

-call 3rd party programs with subprocess.call():

FileLocker http://www.jensscheffler.de/filelocker (https://superuser.com/questions/294826/how-to-purposefully-exclusively-lock-a-file)

Easy File Locker http://www.xoslab.com/efl.html and Dispatch (from win32com.client import Dispatch), although last choice is the most complex

Comment: Though i havent tried yet ,but the solution invloving `filelocker` does seem feasible.when i get time i will try that and inform you

Answer (score 9):

It appears you want to lock access to resources where the lock persists *between program invocations*. You need a different strategy for that.

Create a lock file using exclusive create mode; in Python 2 this requires using the [`os.open()` call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) (followed by [`os.fdopen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fdopen) to produce a Python file object), in Python 3 you can use the `'x'` mode when using the built-in `open()`.

In Python 2:

```
import os

LOCKFILE = r'some\path\to\lockfile'


class AlreadyLocked(Exception):
    pass


def lock():
    try:
        fd = os.open(LOCKFILE, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL)
    except IOError:
        # file already exists
        raise AlreadyLocked()
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as lockfile:
        # write the PID of the current process so you can debug
        # later if a lockfile can be deleted after a program crash
        lockfile.write(os.getpid())


def unlock():
     os.remove(LOCKFILE)
```

In Python 3 the `lock()` function would be:

```
def lock():
    try:
        with open(LOCKFILE, 'x') as lockfile:
            # write the PID of the current process so you can debug
            # later if a lockfile can be deleted after a program crash
            lockfile.write(os.getpid())
    except IOError:
         # file already exists
        raise AlreadyLocked()
```

You need to use exclusive create mode to avoid race conditions; in exclusive create mode the file can only be created if it doesn't yet exist, a condition checked by the Operating System, rather than by a separate step in Python which would open a window for another program to create the lock as well.

Now you can lock and unlock without tracking the file descriptor. The lockfile is now a *signal file*; if it is present something has claimed a lock, and deleting the file means something is unlocked.

This does mean that access to the files or directories you are trying to protect is only protected because all your code honours this lock system, not because the OS is enforcing locks on those files or directories.

This all means that this only works if *all access* to the shared resource is handled by processes that cooperate in this strategy. It cannot be used if another process doesn't honour this scheme. In that case your *only option* is to use OS level locking and you have to keep your process running for the full duration of the lock.

Comment: I tried this but i can still access the `lockfile`.I can make changes to it.Like using `potalocker` the file is totally locked.Nothing can be written to it.I guess it is not across processes exaclty.

Comment: @vks: that is what my answer is stating. You use the lockfile as a *signal*. Other processes would look for the same signal. If the file is present already other processes should not try and read or write to anything your process should have exclusive access to.

Comment: @vks: `LOCKFILE` here is **not** the resource you want to lock, by the way!

Comment: I fear that wont work :(....the other process which accesses the file , i have no control over it....

Comment: @vks: you cannot use OS-level locks on files across processes. You can only lock a file exclusively *within* a process. In other words, you cannot do what you want unless the other processes sharing the resource *cooperates*.

Comment: i guess i have hit a dead end!!!!!! i thought using file attributes it was possible....

Comment: @vks: sorry, then the answer is simply *you cannot do that*. I've edited my answer to clarify that more.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to delete the question; hopefully the answers are helpful to others too. Your bounty will be gone; you pay it up front to get attention and it is not refundable.

Comment: You cannot delete the question because you received more than one answer to it already. The question and answers together now form a collective work, deleting it would take away the work I put into my answer (as well as the work James put into *his* post).

Comment: If you don't do anything, half of the bounty will automatically be awarded to the highest voted answer posted after you started the bounty (provided it has at least a score of 2); so far only my answer would qualify. If you were to mark an answer as accepted (and that answer was posted after you started the bounty) then that answer will get the *full* bounty automatically awarded. Or you can manually award the bounty.

Comment: From a purely selfish perspective, I'd of course *prefer* it if you awarded the bounty to my answer; I did find your question because you posted a bounty on it, and I was partly motivated to write an answer because of the chance to win that bounty. :-) But how you award it is up to you; the only option not available to you is a bounty refund.

Comment: You will get half of it. :P  ..I was tempted to award as i know there cannot be an answer but still feel i should wait.....

Answer (score 1):

there is a method in win32api to set file attributes if you have a read of the following:
[python SetFileAttributes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303343-changing-file-attributes-on-windows/)
[MSDN file attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx)

these give you the python method to set file attributes:
win32api.SetFileAttributes(file, win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)
where file is the name/path of the file, and not a file object
and the second argument is a attribute mask, is you wanted to set several attributes at once, you can use bitwise xor to add them:
win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY

and there are more constants named in the MSDN page.

EDIT:
for file locking you can also look at the [win32file.LockFileEx](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32file__LockFileEx_meth.html) method

i haven't used this before so it may take some playing around, but it appears to need you to pass it a file object (not a path) and then certain constants to set the access permissions, more info on the constants can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: is there and `exclusive lock` as well for the file attributes?It should give error `the file is being used by another process`

Comment: Cant use `win32file.LockFileEx` as it requires a file handle and i cant use that.