# Python multiprocess: synchronization of processes not spawned by the same script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocess

As per subject, I'm trying to understand if there is a way to synchronize different  processes which have not been created by a main/master script.

The scenario is this: my python script is scheduled via Windows scheduler several times per day, sometimes also in parallel. The script instances have to write information on a certain set of shared files, but since I can have concurrent access to those files I need a way to synchronize them.
I'm looking to the multiprocess module in python, but it seems to me that it only handles scenarios in which the subprocesses are spawned by a main one.
Am I correct? can you point me out strategies to achieve what I need?

Comment: That does seem to be outside the domain of multiprocessing, which is essentially just a threading module for Python (where threads don't work well). What you're looking for will probably require you to define your own synchronization logic, either through locking files, coordinating through some multi-process messaging/event framework, or something else. It's going to end up being very OS-dependent, but locking files sounds like it should handle most of what you're looking for ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344366/lock-file-for-access-on-windows))

Comment: It's possible to synchronize unrelated processes, even on separate nodes, with use of `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager` and e.g. using a `threading.Lock` in the server process which you expose over proxies to the client processes. But in your case this would be overkill. Have a look at the [filelock](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/) module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem and the best solution found so far (I'm not really happy with it, actually) is FileLock.

Here's an example:

```
from filelock import FileLock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock_file_name = 'lockfile.lck'
    lock = FileLock(lock_file_name)
    with lock:
        print('Hi from Python script!')
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            print(f"Current value is: {i}")
        print('Python script ended!')
```

Here, even launching multiple instances of the script at the same time, the code in the `with lock:` block is executed in exclusive way.