# Can I lock an Excel file while I am reading it in my python function?

Tags: python, excel, locking

I am reading an Excel file and making minor changes of updating some columns. During this process I do not want the Excel file to be tampered with or someone to open and make changes to it and once the code gets run completely it should be unlocked so that we can view the changes.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't say what library you are using to read the file. That matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `portalocker` to lock a file. Just open the file like `f = open("test.xlsx", "r")` and lock it with `portalocker.lock(f, portalocker.LOCK_EX)`, you can unlock the file with `portalocker.unlock(f)`. You won't be able to open or edit the file while it is locked.

Found in this question: [Lock file for access on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344366/lock-file-for-access-on-windows)